# Setup a PayPal developer account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am building a demo website for my client. I want to use 'hosted checkout pages' with 'PayPal Advanced'. I have very basic questions:

1. What type of PayPal account should I (not my client) create for the demo?
2. Should I create a sandbox account ONLY or do I need a real PayPal account?

PLEASE HELP!!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For testing with the Payflow Gateway (Payments Advanced or Payments Pro) you only need a manager.paypal.com account in test mode.

You need to create an account on https://manager.paypal.com/

Follow the guide at https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929

Check out https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/embedded_checkout_design_guide.pdf for information on developing for PayPal Advanced.